# free struct of unions in c

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, unions

I have a dynamically allocated vector of a special struct, and i trying to free but the software always crashes

the structure is :

```
typedef struct {
    Type_e type;
    union {
        char m_char;
        int m_int;
        // more types (non of them is a pointer)
    } my_data;
} Data_t;
```

where Type is an enum that contain all possible data types.

I allocate and initialize the vector as follows

```
void vector(Data_t **vec, UInt32_t start_element, UInt32_t end_element, Type_e type)
{
    UInt32_t i;
    Data_t  *vec_ptr;

    *vec=(Data_t *)malloc((size_t) ((end_element-start_element+1) * sizeof(Data_t)));

    vec_ptr = *vec;

    if (!vec_ptr) 
    {
        // Write error 
    }

    for (i =start_element; i <= end_element + 1; i++)
    {
        vec_ptr->type = type;
        switch (type)
        {
        case UINT32: vec_ptr->my_data.m_int = 0; break;
        // more possible cases
        default:
            break;
        }
        (vec_ptr)++;
    }
}
```

I call this function as follows

```
Data_t *lVector = NULL;
vector(&lVector,0,10,INT32)
```

but when I try to free the allocated memory as follows,

```
free (lVector+start_element-1);
```

I tried

```
free (lVector+start_element);
```

and

```
free (lVector);
```

were start_element = 0 (in this case)

But in all cases, it crash. Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Standard warning: do not cast `void *` as used by `malloc`&friends.

Comment: given the posted method for allocating 'vec',  use 'free(vec);' to free it. (or if free'd in the caller, use 'free(lvector);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this parameter says array of pointers to type 'Data_t'

```
Data_t **vec,
```

however, this line:

```
*vec=(Data_t *)malloc((size_t) ((end_element-start_element+1) * sizeof(Data_t)));
```

allocates memory for an array of 'Data_t' not an array of pointers to 'Data_t'

in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc

the parameter to malloc() is automatically a 'size_t' so casting to 'size_t' just clutters the code

---

This line:

```
for (i =start_element; i <= end_element + 1; i++)
```

iterates over the array from index 0 to index 11  however, the valid index is from 0 to 10 as C array indexs start with 0 and end at sizeof(array) -1

---

this line:

```
(*vec)->type = type;
```

is expecting 'vec' to actually be an array of pointers to struct.  But, as mentioned earlier, it is not

---

this line:

```
*vec  = *vec + sizeof(Data_t);
```

is properly stepping through the array of struct  However, this looses the pointer to the malloc'd memory, resulting in a memory leak because the pointer to malloc'd memory is lost so cannot be passed to free()

---

This line:

```
*vec = *vec - ((end_element-start_element+1) * sizeof(Data_t));
```

doesn't quite work, because the prior 'for' statement iterates one too many times.

Strongly suggest indexing off 'vec' rather than changing vec contents.  I.E. vec[i]

Comment: Thanks for the information about casting to size_t :)

Comment: about iterating over the array, the idea is for any requested vector of size from 0 to 10, there will be an extra 1 element that will contain encryption data. So I adding an extra element when i allocated memory in malloc. Yes there is a mistake with "<=", it should be "<". removing the equal worked Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

This is incorrect:

```
*vec  = *vec + sizeof(Data_t);
```

It advances `*vec` by `sizeof(Data_t)*sizeof(Data_t)` bytes, because pointer arithmetics multiplies integral constants by `sizeof(*p)` automatically.

Replace with `(*vec)++`, and let the compiler do the math for you. Similarly, remove multiplication in all places where you manipulate pointers. The only place in your code where you need to multiply by `sizeof` is when you call `malloc`.

**Note:** your code is hard to read because you move `*vec` back and forth as you go through the loop. You would be better off declaring and using a plain temporary pointer for iterating the vector, and keeping `*vec` fixed to whatever has been allocated by `malloc`.

Comment: Thanks for correcting this mistake, and I think your way of doing is more readable. Please see my edited code. However, these changes does not fix the issue with freeing the allocated memory. Do you anything else I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You must `free` exactly the pointer returned by `malloc`, and do so exactly once. You store the return value of `malloc` in `*vec`, so `free(*vec)` would be correct in the same function or `free(lVector)` in the calling function. *However*, you subsequently assign other values to `*vec`, so to be able to `free` it correctly you would need to somehow restore the original return value of `malloc` (a better choice would almost certainly be to use another variable instead).

You also seem to misunderstand pointer arithmetic. `p += n` already advances the address pointed to by `sizeof(*p) * n`. So you mustn't multiply the changes to `*vec` by `sizeof(Data_t)` (which is `sizeof(**vec)`).

Comment: About free(vec), this is was a type, I am sorry for the type and I corrected it in the question. I should be free(lVector).

Comment: For the second part of the comment, I re-did the code with @dasblinkenlight comments to make correct, but still crashes when i free the allocated  memory. Anything else I am missing? or incorrectly coded?

Comment: @rasred2004 Just to be sure you are freeing the original pointer, how about you remove the `vec` parameter from your function altogether, instead do `Data_t * const vec = malloc(…)` and have the function `return vec` and the caller does `Data_t * const lVector = vector(0,10,INT32);` then later `free(lVector)`.

Comment: @rasred2004 Also note that your `for` loop goes out of bounds; `i` goes from `start_element` to `end_element + 1` (inclusive), but you only `malloc` space for `end_element - start_element + 1`. If start and end were 0 and 1, you would allocate for 2 elements but the loop would execute for 0, 1, and 2 which is 3, not 2, elements. You need to change the `+ 1` to `+ 2` in `malloc` or remove the `+ 1` from the loop condition. (And note that if you ever index the array, e.g., `lVector[i]`, the first index is always 0, even if `start_element` is something else.)

Answer (score 0):

Where do you try to call `free()`?

If inside `vector()`, you will free '&lVector', which's on the Stack and can't be freed.

You can only free space you allocated with `malloc()`, so you can free `*vec`, but not vec.

Comment: I am trying to free the allocated memory in the calling function, not inside vector() function. I tried free(&lVector), but it is crash :(